# problema con relacion eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy mostrando una tabla (ejercisios) donde tiene columnas relacionadas, estoy intentando que me muestre el nombre del id_nivel (medio,bajo,alto) en vez de que me salga el id (1,2,3) pero me da un error, adjunto todo lo necesario

**MODEL NIVEL**

```js
class Nivel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'nivel_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idnivel_table';
    protected $fillable = [
        'idnivel_table',
        'nombre'
    ];

        public function nivel()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('app\Ejercisio');
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```js
public function ejercisios_total() {
  $ejercisios_total = Ejercisio::all();
  $lista_nivel = Nivel::with('nivel')->get();
  $lista_Tipo = TipoEjercisio::all();
  return view('admin.ejercisios.index', compact('ejercisios_total', 'lista_nivel', 'lista_Tipo'));
}
```

HTML

```html
@foreach($ejercisios_total as $ejetotal)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $ejetotal -> nombre_ejercisio}}</td>
  <td>{{ $ejetotal -> cantidad_ejercisio}}</td>
  <td>{{ $ejetotal -> repeticiones_ejercisio}}</td>
  <td>{{ $ejetotal -> id_nivel->nombre}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

ERROR
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu tabla `ejercisios_table` tienes una columna `idnivel_table`?

Comment: tengo uno que se llama id_nivel @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Le estás indicando al modelo que la clave primaria es esa `protected $primaryKey = 'idnivel_table';`

Comment: te explico, en mi tabla ejercisios tengo un (FK) llamada "id_nivel" y la tabla "nivel" con la id "idnivel_table"